# Scala: subtyping polymorphism vs universal polymorphism

Tags: scala, oop, generics, polymorphism, type-systems

I think I know what subtyping polymorphism is.

What is universal polymorphism and how are the two different?

From: [Programming in Scala, Third Edition](https://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_3ed):

> 10.9 Polymorphism and dynamic binding
>
> You saw in Section 10.4 that a variable of type `Element` could refer to
>   an object of type `ArrayElement`. The name for this phenomenon is
>   polymorphism, which means "many shapes" or "many forms." In this case,
>   `Element` objects can have many forms.[7]
>
> .....
>
> [7] This kind of polymorphism is called subtyping polymorphism.
>   Another kind of polymorphism in Scala called universal polymorphism is
>   discussed in Chapter 19.

Chapter 19 does not mention the term "universal polymorphism". It does talk about Type Parameterization (generics). So I guess "universal polymorphism" is a fancy name for type prameterization? But isn't subtyping polymorphism a private case of type Parameterization?

Comment: I wish polymorphism weren't such an overloaded term. Subtyping is sometimes referred to as "subtyping polymorphism" while generics are referred to a "parametric polymorphism". No, subtyping is not a special case of parametric polymorphism (although discussions of variance end up involving both subjects)

Comment: I wish people were not using comments for one-liner answers.

Comment: I don't consider my comment an answer. If you do, feel free to post it as an answer. Answering as a community-wiki is one way to do this without appearing to be begging for upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when talking about [Universal Polymorphism](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Programming_Languages/Universal_Polymorphism), we refer to two things:

1. Parameteric Polymorphism (A.K.A type parameterization, A.K.A generics)
2. Inclusion Polymorphism  (A.K.A subtyping polymorphism)

They are not directly related, but rather two branches of the same root. We do mix them when we start talking about the "is subtype of" relation regarding variance, when we ask questions like "Given that giraffe is a subtype of animal, is a box of giraffes a subtype of a box of animal?"